# AngularJS: help registering custom service the right way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

**Newbie Question**

Have been watching this [great Angular Beginners course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEM8lVLqRzg&index=7&list=PLBTXLYhPD8MHGMW-ZEvdAtkxyAz-N8Toj) but got stuck in the register process.

[Code project (plnkr.co)](http://plnkr.co/edit/vJXE7w?p=preview)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="githubViewer">

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="github.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>

    {{ countdown }}
    <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)">
      <input type="search" required placeholder="Username to find" ng-model="username"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

    <div ng-include="'userdetails.html'" ng-show="user"> </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

github.js

```
(function() {

  var github = function($http) { // requires the service $http

    // Private implementation details //
    var gettingUser = function(username) {
      return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        });
      /* returning the promise that already comes with 
      the function to perform the data extration
      */
    };

    var gettingRepos = function(user) {
      return $http.get(user.repos_url)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        });
      /* returning a promise that it will return the data
      - so the controller doesn't have to. */
    };



    // Public API //
    return {
      gettingUser: gettingUser,
      gettingRepos: gettingRepos
    };
    // returns an object (github service)
  };


  var module = angular.module("githubViewer");
  /* Not creating a module, just getting the reference 
  to the one created in script.js So no need to list 
  the dependencies in a list after githubViewer*/

  // Register the Service
  module.factory("$github", github);
}());
```

script.js

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("githubViewer", []);

  var MainController = function(
    $scope, $github, $interval, $log, 
    $anchorScroll, $location) {

    var onUserComplete = function(data) {
      $scope.user = data;
      $github.gettingRepos($scope.user)
        .then(onRepos, onError);
    };

    var onRepos = function(data){
      $scope.repos = data;
      $anchorScroll( $location.hash("userDetails") );
    }

    var onError = function(reason) {
      $scope.error = "Could not fetch data";
    };

    var decrementCountdown = function(){
      $scope.countdown -= 1;
      if($scope.countdown < 1){
        $scope.search($scope.username);
      }
    }

    $scope.search = function(username) {
      $log.info("Searching for "+ username);
      $github.gettingUser(username).then(onUserComplete, onError);

      if(countdownIntervalObj){
        $interval.cancel(countdownIntervalObj);
        $scope.countdown = null;
      }
    };

    var countdownInterval = null;
    var startCountdown = function(){
      countdownIntervalObj = $interval(decrementCountdown, 1000, $scope.countdown);
    }


    $scope.username = "angular";
    $scope.message = "GitHub Viewer";
    $scope.repoSortOrder = "-stargazers_count";
    $scope.countdown = 5;

    startCountdown();
  };

  app.controller("MainController", 
  ["$scope", "$http", "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location", "$github", MainController]);

}());
```

The console keeps saying that the `$github.gettingUser` is not a function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe switch the scripts script.js with github.js >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out for the order when you inject your dependencies as you are injecting seven but just passing six to the controller in the wrong order. You need to pass `$http` and put `$github` at the end.

```
var MainController = function($scope, $http, $interval, $log, $anchorScroll, $location, $github)

app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location", "$github", MainController]);
```

Comment: Wow that was a quick answer! Thank you very much, sir.

Comment: Is there an easy way to keep these two sync. Like making a list of strings with them and somehow reference that instead. `var parList = ["$scope", "$http", ..]; var MainController = function( parList ) {..}; app.controller("MainController", parList);`

Comment: You can use the `$inject` property but still paying attention to the order `MainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', ...]` or rely on a tool like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) and forget about annotating.

Answer (score 1):

When you inject resources into your controller

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location", "$github", MainController]);
```

order et type must match your controller function declaration

```
var MainController = function(
$scope, $github, $interval, $log, 
$anchorScroll, $location) {
```

So here what $github contains is the $http module :)

Here is a corrected version of your plunkr 
http://plnkr.co/edit/9UyNHDKiXDZAZt8PPEPy?p=preview
However I prefer this syntax, I find it more clear: http://plnkr.co/edit/byhQ7ST8AZlQ6oMYIMeV?p=preview

You should take a look to https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide
A styleguide were using at work, filled with best practices.
Have fun with angular

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

because the order of providers are not the same in the array ["scope", "github", etc] with the controller's. your service corresponds to another provider which is minified, even if it is not, it does not matter. you have to pass the injectors in the same order you define in the provider array